# How to fix //NOI18N in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, spring, netbeans

I have a problem with Netbeans' auto-generated *initComponents()* method in my Swing app.

The problem is that it is generating bundle with no respect for locale:

```
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("myapp/Bundle_en"); // NOI18N
```

instead of:

```
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("myapp/Bundle", myLocale);
```

I've tried to set default locale to desired one before calling *initComponents()*, but it does not work for me. The result is that my UI has mixed languages.

Could anyone explain me what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be able to change generated code if you open your source and go to `Tools | Internationalization | Internationalize...`. There you can customize what expression is used to obtain I18N'ed value.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I had to turn off "Automatic Internalization" in design mode in first place and than I could do what you had advised